# Python - Find Days Diff Grouping by Member

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking to find an efficient way to generate the number of days diff from an initial point in time. The initial point in time the first time (min date) an ID is triggered by the value Y in the Indicator column.

Input

```
ID   Indicator  Date
111  Y          1/20/2020
111  N          1/23/2020
111  Y          1/26/2020
111  N          1/26/2020
123  N          1/1/2020
123  Y          1/23/2020
123  Y          2/5/2020
```

Output

```
ID   Indicator  Date         Daysdiff
111  Y          1/20/2020    0
111  N          1/23/2020    3
111  Y          1/26/2020    6
111  N          1/26/2020    6
123  N          1/1/2020     -22
123  Y          1/23/2020    0 
123  Y          2/5/2020     12
```

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Daysdiff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().fillna('')
```

My difficulty is figuring out how to implement the starting point, where  day 0 should be when an ID has an Indicator of Y at their earliest point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try  with `groupby().idxmax`:

```
idx = df['Indicator'].eq('Y').groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')
df['Daysdiff'] = df['Date'] - df.loc[idx, 'Date'].values
```

Output:

```
    ID Indicator       Date Daysdiff
0  111         Y 2020-01-20   0 days
1  111         N 2020-01-23   3 days
2  111         Y 2020-01-26   6 days
3  111         N 2020-01-26   6 days
4  123         N 2020-01-01 -22 days
5  123         Y 2020-01-23   0 days
6  123         Y 2020-02-05  13 days
```

Note that since `'Y' > 'N'`, the following should have worked, but it doesn't on my system:

```
idx = df['Indicator'].groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')
```

Comment: Quick question, would you happen to know why I would receive the following error " unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"? It occurs when I try to run your second line of code - thanks!

Comment: Your date Column is still string. Did you forget `pd.to_datetime` as in your question?

Comment: Thank you and sorry...I did forget that!

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort, and then get the `first` date with `groupby`. Then get the difference:

```
first = (df.sort_values(['ID', 'Indicator', 'Date'], ascending=[True,False,True])
           .groupby('ID')['Date'].transform('first'))
df['Daysdiff'] = (df['Date'] - first).dt.days
df
Out[1]: 
    ID Indicator       Date  Daysdiff
0  111         Y 2020-01-20         0
1  111         N 2020-01-23         3
2  111         Y 2020-01-26         6
3  111         N 2020-01-26         6
4  123         N 2020-01-01       -22
5  123         Y 2020-01-23         0
6  123         Y 2020-02-05        13
```